# htaccess how can i ignore a directory and foward to a file with same name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a social network application that would allow users to create a custom name. I created a dummy test account with the name "images" so my URL address would be www.example.com/images. The issue I'm having is when i go to search for the user www.example.com/images i am forwarded to the directory called "images/" instead www.example.com/images/ ...how can i ignore the directory and get forwarded to the vanity URL page instead?

Thanks for any help in advance.

This is the htaccess code that I'm currently using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 

#hide htaccess file from view
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#disable directory listing
Options -Indexes

#Vanity URL
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ profile.php?u=$1

#Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#errorRedirect
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.example.com/errors/badrequest.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/errors/forbid.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errors/notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/errors/server.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash and doing a redirect. You can use this code:

```
#errorRedirect
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.example.com/errors/badrequest.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/errors/forbid.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errors/notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/errors/server.php

# turn directory slash off
DirectorySlash Off
#disable directory listing
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On 

#hide htaccess file from view
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

#Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Vanity URL
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but the code you provided does not work. the code forwards me to a 403 forbidden page. Do you have any other suggestions that might help me out?

Comment: I made a minor update to my answer. Test this **after clearing browser cache** or in Chrome dev tool.